# Email DNS Setup: How do I make HELO publish an SPF record? SPF_HELO_NONE - SPF: HELO does not publish an SPF Record

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf, txt-record

**My environment: hMailServer 5.6.8 on Windows Server 2022 Standard**

Let's say I have two domains (I don't really own these domains, they're just examples), `www.myblog.com` and `www.mailserver.com`. They are both hosted on the same machine and have the same IP address `1.2.3.4`.

The blog site `www.myblog.com` uses `www.mailserver.com` to send emails. The site `www.mailserver.com` only serves as a mail server; it is not accessible from a browser. I have set it up so that when `www.myblog.com` sends an email to someone, the recipient's email server receives `SENT: EHLO www.mailserver.com`, but sees `SENT: MAIL FROM:<noreply@myblog.com>` message, so the recipient sees that the email came from `myblog.com`.

Like mentioned before, the current EHLO message is `SENT: EHLO www.mailserver.com`

Everything is working fine so far. Recently I decided to check the "spam rating" of my setup at https://www.mail-tester.com. I sent an email to the spam tester using the setup described above, and I saw a warning under the *SpamAssassin* section that says

> SPF_HELO_NONE        SPF: HELO does not publish an SPF Record

My question is, how do I get rid of this warning? Are the DNS records as they should be? See below for the DNS records for each domain.

[image]

The DNS records for each domain are as follows (note the PTR record for 1.2.3.4):

```
IP address 1.2.3.4
PTR www.mailserver.com

myblog.com
Name            Type    Value
@               A       1.2.3.4
*               A       1.2.3.4
@               MX      10 myblog.com.
@               TXT     v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 ~all
dkim._domainkey TXT     v=DKIM1; t=s; k=rsa; p=[super long public key string]

mailserver.com
Name            Type    Value
@               A       1.2.3.4
*               A       1.2.3.4
@               MX      10 mailserver.com.
@               TXT     v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 ~all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the warning by adding an extra TXT record with the name "www" to the `www.mailserver.com` DNS:

```
mailserver.com
Name            Type    Value
@               A       1.2.3.4
*               A       1.2.3.4
@               MX      10 mailserver.com.
@               TXT     v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 ~all
www             TXT     v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 ~all <-- adding this record fixed the warning
```

Comment: Why do you use `www.mailserver.com`? That's just strange. But yes, the spf record must match the domain name present. @ matches `mailserver.com` in this case, *not* `www.mailserver.com`.

Comment: @vidarlo The PTR record for the IP is `www.mailserver.com`, so I had to make HELO/EHLO domain match the PTR record with "www"